# Handling multiple publishers in C# with eventhandlers

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, publish-subscribe

I am currently trying to learn a bit about Eventhandling in C# and I am currently testing stuff out and I have created this little testing program.

```
public class Message : EventArgs {

    public string message { get; set; }
    public Message(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

}

public class Component {

    public event EventHandler<Message> onComponentEvent;
    public string uuid;
    public Component () {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        uuid = g.ToString();
    }
    public void update () {
        Task.Factory.StartNew (() => componentEvent (uuid)); 
    }
    private void componentEvent (string message) {
        onComponentEvent?.Invoke(this, new Message(message));
    }
}

public class Entity {
    List<Component> components;
    public EventHandler<Message> EntityEvent;
    public Entity () {
        components = new List<Component>();
    }

    public void addComponent () {
        var c = new Component();
        c.onComponentEvent += ComponentEvents;
        this.components.Add (c);
    }

    public void update () {
        System.Console.WriteLine("I am an entity and I am updating");
        foreach (Component c in this.components) {
            c.update ();
        }
    }

    private void ToManagerEvent (String message) {
        EntityEvent?.Invoke(this, new Message(message));
    }

    private void ComponentEvents (object source, Message e) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew ( () => ToManagerEvent ( e.message ));
    }

}

public class Manager {
    List<Entity> entities;
    public EventHandler<Message> ManagerEvent;
    public Manager () {
        this.entities = new List<Entity>();
    }

    public void addEntity (Entity e) {
        e.EntityEvent += EntityEvents;
        this.entities.Add(e);
    }

    public void update () {
        foreach ( Entity e in entities ) {
            e.update ();
        }   
    }
    private void ToGameManagerEvent (Message message) {
        ManagerEvent?.Invoke(this, message);
    }    
    private void EntityEvents (object source, Message e) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.message);
        Task.Factory.StartNew ( () => ToGameManagerEvent (e));
    }
}

public class GameManager {
    ConcurrentQueue<Entity> queue;
    Manager manager;
    public GameManager () {
        this.queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Entity>();
        this.manager = new Manager();
        this.manager.ManagerEvent += ManagerEvents;
        Entity e1 = new Entity();
        e1.addComponent();
        this.manager.addEntity(e1);
    }

    public void update () {
        while (this.queue.TryDequeue(out Entity en)){
            manager.addEntity(en);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("begin update");
        manager.update();
    }

    private void ManagerEvents (object source, Message e) {
        queue.Enqueue (new Entity());
    }
}    
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GameManager gm = new GameManager();
        //1
        gm.update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        //2
        gm.update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        //4
        gm.update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        //8
        gm.update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    }
}
```

In short this program is supposed to have an update loop where for each update a component fires off an event, that bubbles up from `Component -> Entity -> Manager -> GameManager`. Where the `Gamemanager` then adds a new `Entity` in a queue and tries to dequeue and add it to the `managers` `entity` list before each manager update.

Expected behavior => every update doubles the amount of entities.
Behavior occurring => only one component fires off an event that gets bubbled up which results in only 1 new entity each update.

Thus there is an issue when subscribed to multiple publishers at the same time? I am assuming there is something fundamental about this I am misunderstanding so any pointers to what I am doing wrong would be very welcome.

Comment: You need to learn the c# naming conventions. There are tons of issues with your code just to comply with the normal naming of your identifiers.

Comment: There's also a lot of code here that doesn't seem necessary. You've got tasks, queues, etc. going on, when your question is _about_ events in C#. Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you're asking about. Also explain in detail what you've already done in order to try to debug the issue and figure out what's going on, and what _specifically_ it is you need help with. Stack Overflow is not an appropriate forum for you to have someone tutor you on language features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in your code is this:

```
private void ManagerEvents (object source, Message e) {
    queue.Enqueue (new Entity());
}
```

You're just adding a plain `Entity`. There are no components firing events.

What you should have done is this:

```
private void ManagerEvents (object source, Message e) {
    Entity e1 = new Entity();
    e1.addComponent();
    queue.Enqueue (e1);
}
```

Now you get the output that I think you were expecting:

```
begin update
I am an entity and I am updating
fdc40694-fcf9-4f49-b2b1-29ff9735214f
begin update
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
fdc40694-fcf9-4f49-b2b1-29ff9735214f
a05b42fa-5c77-4d4c-a59c-b7f85bdcf1cc
begin update
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
fdc40694-fcf9-4f49-b2b1-29ff9735214f
a05b42fa-5c77-4d4c-a59c-b7f85bdcf1cc
6dfd20ed-72c5-4fde-b41f-0fa250d3b760
d343a7b3-a7e1-4785-8bd7-1df3cb947255
begin update
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
a05b42fa-5c77-4d4c-a59c-b7f85bdcf1cc
fdc40694-fcf9-4f49-b2b1-29ff9735214f
1b02458c-e015-4cb8-81d6-26e8f94821fc
d343a7b3-a7e1-4785-8bd7-1df3cb947255
6dfd20ed-72c5-4fde-b41f-0fa250d3b760
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
I am an entity and I am updating
1b06f9fd-1f94-4db0-a6ff-7574c833af9c
2cb02ff4-eb18-4024-92cf-1d098bde476a
5b674091-2f8f-4613-9aba-274aee938e94
```

I also did a bit of an update of your code to make it more compliant with the regular naming conventions, etc.

Try this:

```
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }
}

public class Component
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> ComponentEvent;
    public string Uuid { get; private set; }

    public Component()
    {
        this.Uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("      Component.UpdateAsync() - Begin");
        await this.OnComponentEventAsync(this.Uuid);
        Console.WriteLine("      Component.UpdateAsync() - End");
    }

    protected virtual void OnComponentEvent(string message)
    {
        this.ComponentEvent?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(message));
    }

    protected virtual Task OnComponentEventAsync(string message)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.OnComponentEvent(message));
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    private List<Component> _components;
    public EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> EntityEvent;

    public Entity()
    {
        _components = new List<Component>();
    }

    public void AddComponent()
    {
        var c = new Component();
        c.ComponentEvent += this.ComponentEvent;
        _components.Add(c);
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    Entity.UpdateAsync() - Begin");
        foreach (Component c in _components)
        {
            await c.UpdateAsync();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("    Entity.UpdateAsync() - End");
    }

    protected virtual void OnEntityEvent(string message)
    {
        this.EntityEvent?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(message));
    }

    protected virtual Task OnEntityEventAsync(string message)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.OnEntityEvent(message));
    }

    private async void ComponentEvent(object source, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        await this.OnEntityEventAsync(e.Message);
    }
}

public class Manager
{
    private List<Entity> _entities;
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> ManagerEvent;

    public Manager()
    {
        _entities = new List<Entity>();
    }

    public void AddEntity(Entity e)
    {
        e.EntityEvent += this.EntityEvent;
        _entities.Add(e);
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Manager.UpdateAsync() - Begin");
        foreach (var e in _entities)
        {
            await e.UpdateAsync();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("  Manager.UpdateAsync() - End");
    }

    protected virtual void OnManagerEvent(string message)
    {
        this.ManagerEvent?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(message));
    }

    protected virtual Task OnManagerEventAsync(string message)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.OnManagerEvent(message));
    }

    private async void EntityEvent(object source, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        await this.OnManagerEventAsync(e.Message);
    }
}

public class GameManager
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Entity> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Entity>();
    private Manager _manager = new Manager();

    public GameManager()
    {
        _manager.ManagerEvent += this.ManagerEvent;

        var entity = new Entity();
        entity.AddComponent();
        _manager.AddEntity(entity);
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("GameManager.UpdateAsync() - Begin");
        while (_queue.TryDequeue(out var entity))
        {
            _manager.AddEntity(entity);
        }
        await _manager.UpdateAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("GameManager.UpdateAsync() - End");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    private void ManagerEvent(object source, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = new Entity();
        entity.AddComponent();
        _queue.Enqueue(entity);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gm = new GameManager();
        //1
        await gm.UpdateAsync();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        //2
        await gm.UpdateAsync();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        //4
        await gm.UpdateAsync();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        //8
        await gm.UpdateAsync();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    }
}
```